# How can I align my emoji just next to the heading text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align my image right next to when the heading ends i.e next to "Sample Text".

Currently the container which contains heading and emoji is a `flexbox`.

```
.container{
display:flex;

.heading-text {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1.33;
}

.emoji-img{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
align-self: flex-end;
}
```

I've tried using `grid` too but cant find a way. What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would use simpler code, you have the solution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.heading-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  padding-right: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.emoji-img {
  padding-bottom: .1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading-text">
    Some text<br>
    Some more<br>
    Heading text
  </div>
  <img class="emoji-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8?s=20&d=identicon" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works when the heading is in one line when its a long one in two or more lines, the image doesnt stay in the right place. I need a fix for that, so that image ends up just next to the heading's end.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-items` for vertical aligning and `justify-content` for horizontal aligning.

For more, you can read about [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here.

Here is an example for you:

```css
.container{
/* edited here*/
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid red
}

.heading-text {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1.33;
}

.emoji-img{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="headering-text">Hello, World!</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, this works fine when the heading text is of one line but the image doesnt stay at the required position when the heading is in two or more lines? What can i do for that? Shall using `position:absolute` and `left: calc(something)`  solve it? I cant figure out

Comment: Then set the ``position absolute`` and the ``top: 50%`` and ``right 0``. This will help you centralize the photo. Don't forget to give ``position relative`` to your *container*. If this answers your problem, I would be pleased if you accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: `right:0` would position it to the right but not just at the end of the heading. I need a way i can position `right` dynamically calculating the heading's end.

Comment: I showed you have to cook not to give the food to you. lol, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Simply put it there

```css
.heading-text {width: 170px; font:16px/1.33 sans-serif;}
.emoji-img:after {content: ""; font-style: normal;}
```

```html
<div class="heading-text">
  THIS IS THE SAMPLE TEXT HELLO HELLO Sample Text <i class="emoji-img"></i>
</div>
```